# What should I use to organize my music (iTunes, Windows Media Player...)?

Tags: music, ipod

I have a PC with Windows Vista, and an iPod.
I've been using iTunes, but it has several things I don't like.
Should I use iTunes, Windows Media Player or something else to organize my music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the latest Winamp. The Media Library is responsive to searches and there is iPod syncing support.

Answer (score 0):

I use [MediaMonkey](http://mediamonkey.com).

It does playlists, tagging and you can organise your data in several different ways.