# organizing my music and my itunes

Tags: music-management

**What can we do to organize our music?**

I've got over 20k items on my [iTunes Library](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1451), at least 5k with [ratings](https://superuser.com/questions/215988/how-to-back-up-song-ratings-in-itunes) and play counts, apparently just 12k music files and I can't understand how [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/50798/what-should-i-use-to-organize-my-music-itunes-windows-media-player) have **[not been properly answered](https://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music)** yet. Maybe there is [no answer](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bitunes%5D+organize).

[I have](https://superuser.com/questions/63818/removing-duplicates-from-itunes-playlist) too many [duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/178051/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-in-itunes), [broken links](https://superuser.com/questions/223905/filtering-itunes-library-items-by-file-location/223925#223925), bad music, corrupted files... Well, a big mess with no [tags](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Enabled_Applications)!

Probably there's no single software capable of just organizing everything, though I'd love one. Hopefully some time in the near future [we all](http://www.spotify.com/uk/about/features/offline-mode/) will be able to just sync the [cloud](http://www.grooveshark.com) of our automagically selected music to the newly created [offline](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/cloud/363685/open-source-leader-slams-chrome-oss-cloud) copy. But meanwhile...

Please, do consider I've at least gave a shot (even while not a full test drive) to every single answer linked here already, plus a few more. I'm fine with using [other software](http://alternativeto.net/software/itunes/?sort=likes&platform=mac) (**mac** too, please) to organize, but I'd need it to sync (retrieve and put back) at least iTunes ratings, because of iPhone and smart playlists. Not looking for iTunes replacement.

I'm hoping to hear what you hardcore music organizers out there are using as your own solutions! :)

I myself am using way too many tools, getting [way too little](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-rebuilding-or-cleaning-your-itunes-library/) done and end up [going song by song](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20010860-263.html).

Comment: Subjective and argumentative. Consider making this a community wiki perhaps?

Comment: @Daniel I actually tried to make it wiki, but couldn't find how!

Answer (score 1):

there's no simple way to. I have a *system* but it involves a few things. I'd note eventually i have two seperate sets (purely lossy and lossless where possible) that are immaculately tagged

Preferably files should be tagged properly BEFORE they get added to itunes

Each of these programmes handles a specific role

[Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) - for retagging. You can also use the 'convert tags to filename' to seperate out properly tagged music. In my case, it also handles the artist/album settings. You can also correct tags in itunes with the 'show info' options

[musicbrainz picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload) - for files that arn't tagged at all - this 'listens' and attempts to tag - it isn't perfect but invaluble for mystery songs. However, it prefers 'compilations' for individual tracks.

Comment: That's one idea I've been considering... It's basically saying "forget iTunes to organize music, get a good *system*". :)

Comment: if your music is already organised, it wouldn't matter that itunes does. Getting it right to start with is the way to go - the most essential thing i did was start the organisation from scratch - since legacy tagging/organisation just gets in the way.